# how to have a query include an id with its name from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

hi i have two tables "contract" and "users"
contract is like this:

```
contract_id , buyer_id , seller_id , third_person_id
```

and user table is like this:

```
user_id , first_name , last_name
```

i want a query to give me this information:

```
contract_id , buyer_id , buyer_first_name , buyer_last_name , seller_id , seller_first_name , seller_last_name , third_person_id , third_first_name , third_last_name
```

how to get above query?
i want to get names form ids.

Comment: you need 2 joins with user table. One for buyer and one for seller

Comment: would you please write it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use three `join`

```
 select 
          c.contract_id , 
          u.buyer_id , 
          u1.first_name as buyer_first_name , 
          u1.last_name as buyer_last_name , 
          c.seller_id , 
          u2.first_name as seller_first_name , 
          u2.last_name as seller_last_name , 
          c.third_person_id , 
          u3.first_name as third_first_name ,
          u3.last_name as third_last_name
    from contract c
    left join users u1 on u1.user_id=c.buyer_id
    left join users u2 on u2.user_id=c.seller_id
    left join users u3 on u3.user_id=c.third_person_id
```